# C# define xml documentation file for every project

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013, sandcastle

I have a C# solution in visual studio 2013, composed by more projects. Because I have to create documentation with the tool Sandcastle, I need to define, for every project, the build property to create the xml documentation file. It can be done by click dx on the project->properties->build tab-> check the xml documentation file. There is a simple way to define that EVERY project inside my solution has that check, or I have to modify every single project? It would take me so much time...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's the way to do that. You have to configure it for each project you need.